# Applying gzip compression to files served by grunt-contrib-connect

Tags: gruntjs, compression, gzip, connect

It's pretty simple: I want to simulate the page-size of my website using grunt-contrib-connect before I deploy the site onto Apache.

With Apache, it's pretty straight-forward to turn on gzip-compression. However, with grunt-contrib-connect, I haven't found a way to make it work. Here's what I've tried so far in my Gruntfile.js:

```
var compression = require('compression');

...
// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      open: false,
      base: 'dev',
      port: '4000',
      hostname: 'localhost',
      livereload: 35729,
      onCreateServer: [compression()]
    }
  }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
connect: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      open: false,
      base: 'dev',
      port: '4000',
      hostname: 'localhost',
      livereload: 35729,
      middleware: [compression()]
    }
  }
}
```

I can serve the files up correctly, but when I use Chrome Dev tools to look at the Network requests, I can see that no compression is being applied to any files served by the connect webserver. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm... strange, that second example looks like it should be correct (the first one is not). Sorry, but I'm not sure what else could be wrong.

Comment: Found the solution! In the grunt-contrib-connect task, if you supply an `Array` to `middleware`, it will completely replace the default middleware with what you provide.  
But if you specify the `middleware` option as a `function`, it works as you would expect (chaining your middleware to the default middleware):  
    middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
      middlewares.unshift(compression());
      return middlewares;
    }

Comment: Glad you found it! You should add this as an answer to your own question and accept it, that will help other people find the answer if they need it.

Answer (score 4):

In the grunt-contrib-connect task, if you supply an Array to middleware, it will completely replace the default middleware with what you provide. But if you specify the middleware option as a function, it works as you would expect (chaining your middleware to the default middleware

```
middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) { 
    middlewares.unshift(compression()); 
    return middlewares; 
}
```

Comment: Added the comment to the question by OP as answer. Its the correct answer anyway. This helps in marking the question as answered.

Comment: I believe livereload isn't compatible with compression. But, this works otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone, but I had trouble figuring out what to do where the above just uses `compression()`. I assume that's shorthand for a function that will compress files on the fly. Since I didn't find any info that looked like it would tell me how to do that, I just used [grunt-contrib-compress](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress) to gzip all of my files into a new directory.

Gruntfile entry:

```
compress: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      mode: 'gzip'
    },
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'dist/',
    src: ['**/*'],
    dest: 'dist_compress/'
  }
}
```

Then I added a new server entry for `connect`, with a small middleware function to change the `Content-Encoding` header. That allowed me to do local performance tests with gzip enabled.

Gruntfile entry:

```
connect: {

  server_gzip: {
    options: {
      port: 9004,
      livereload: false,
      base: 'dist_compress',
      middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
        middlewares.unshift(function(req, res, next) { 
          res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
          return next(); 
          });

        return middlewares;
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Note that livereload needs to be turned off since that will cause things to fail.